# Frequent usage of identical string as Map key in Java class

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates, refactoring

Consider next scenario:

```
void foo(Map<String, String> params) {
    String myValue = params.get("myKey");
}

void bar(Map<String, String> params) {
    String myValue = params.get("myKey");
}

// ... and so on
```

I would like to define *myKey* as a private static final variable:

```
private static final String MY_KEY = "myKey";
```

And then use it:

```
void foo(Map<String, String> params) {
    String myValue = params.get(MY_KEY);
}
```

Is it a good practice or can we do better?

Comment: This is a primarily opinion based question. Also, I guess is that in your specific use case a dedicated class could be more suitable than a generic map - but I don't know any details.

Comment: The compiler will probably do that for you but by all means make that change. It would indeed improve your code.

Comment: It is definitely a good practice to extract that string to a constant. You should also consider using an `EnumMap` with an enum as the key, as suggested by @HansSchreuder in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its definitely a good practice to extract duplicate string literals into a constant irrespective of whether it is used as a key in Map.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use behavior driven it is better to add the key as param:

```
void foo(Map<String, String> params, String key) {
    String myValue = params.get(key);
}
```

And about the constant, can also put it in a Enum, then you can collect multiple keys in the Enum. Or collect them in a Constants class. Up to you.

Only thing, it is weird you have a void return type. I would expect String:

```
String getFooByKey(Map<String, String> params, String key) {
    return params.get(key);
}
```